# HighLighter Library Qt5/C++ for web languages

Tags: qt

### Hi everybody,

I would like to create an **code editor** on Qt to **highlight** and **complete** web languages.
It's my first steps on Qt and this project is a school project.

I looked for some tutorials on **Qscintilla** or **GNU Scource-Highlight** but I don't know how add it to my project. Of course I seen examples on Qt documentation but I don't like the way to highlight code.

So if someone know how work these libraries or if you have something more new, please answer me ;)

PS : Sorry for my bad English, I'm still learning =D

Comment: If you use Qt and don't like the way the highlightning is done, then forget about Qt. I dont see how you could avoid it anyway. The samples provided show really basic mechanisms you will always have to use with Qt. I think you should start with an easier project, learning step by step.

Comment: i understand what you mean, maybe I was not really clear about this. It's not the way to highlight, but i won't write all regular expression to highlight web language. If you know someone who wrote all regular expression for web language, i take it ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend looking into [Kate Highlighting](https://kate-editor.org/2005/03/24/writing-a-syntax-highlighting-file/), which is also used for example by QtCreator.

I vaguely remember hearing that the Kate and QtCreator developers were actually working on a Qt syntax highlighting library using this syntax definition files.

Might be worth contacting the [Kate developers](https://kate-editor.org/)